# What are the ways to prevent my tammy cat from being pregnant?

Tags: cats

Without changing her personality?

Can we install IUD or something?

My female cat has 4 kittens. She is  nursing her children. Why I love them all, 6 cats are too many.

Also her "husband" was at home when she's looking for mate outside. Is it possible that some of the kitten is her husband's kitten?

Only one look like her husband.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for a litter to include kittens sired by several tomcats. However,  it's also possible for kittens sired by the same tom to have quite different  coat patterns, depending on exactly what mix of genes they get from their two parents. If you are interested,you might want to look up cat genetics and see which coat genes are dominant, which are recessive, and which mix. (Reportedly, an expert can spot something on the order of twelve distinct genetic markers on a running cat several hundred feet away.)

Answer (score 5):

Spay her - the best way to prevent it and benefit her well-being. Spaying her will not change her personality.

There are contraceptive injections but good veterinarians don't like using them as they have high risks of cancer.

Comment: what is spaying? Will it remove the eggs or will it just tie up to tuba fallopy

Comment: Removes ovaries and uterus altogether.

Comment: in hoomin they only tight up the ovaries. can that be done

Comment: No, because removing everything is better for the animal, veterinarians want the best for your pets. Won't hurt to ask but I would highly doubt they'd do it.

Comment: you wouldn't remove ovaries from your daughters why would you do that for your cat? I had cats like that and they just live a pointless life always grumpy all the time

Comment: also the tammy cat is nursing

Comment: I cannot answer the human aspect of it but you don't get any ill effects from spaying your cat, only positive ones.
Female cats tend to be grumpy anyways lol I remember when I was working at the SPCA, we had 2 rooms for cats - one male only and the other female only. You'd walk into the female room and they don't even look at you but as soon as you'd walk into the boys room they would plow you over and want all the love. 

You can spay her a few weeks after she's nursed.

Answer (score 1):

Female cats can have kittens by multiple Toms. What happens is that she mates with multiple males and sperm from different males fertilizes different eggs. Note that just because a kitten looks different, does not mean anything. Cats can sometimes have kittens that look much different, even though they are all from the same sire.

The only way to prevent kittens without altering her body chemistry is to confine her whenever she goes into heat so no intact male can reach her.

There may be a way to abort a cat once she becomes pregnant, but it would involve toxic substances or risky medical steps, like an introduced infection. One mild toxin that has been used for contraception is Queen Anne's Lace, which is kind of like an ancient form of Plan B. The seeds are steeped as a tea and it must be drunk without fail within 24 hours of conception. Even so, it is not reliable.